# using Twitter SDK to send tweet failed, but I'dont know why

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I'm using Twitter SDK to loggin and tweet. Authenticate it's ok, but when use TWTRComposer with a simple text, the SDK callback return 'TWTRComposerResultDone', but the Simulator/Device show 'The tweet "text" cannot be sent because the connection to Twitter failed. 
The debugger show 'plugin com.apple.share.Twitter.post invalidated' but everything aparently is correct.

Is there a bug or I forgot some thing.

My code:

> TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];
>
> [composer setText:@"some text"];
>
> [composer showWithCompletion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {
>          if (result == TWTRComposerResultCancelled) {
>              NSLog(@"Tweet composition cancelled");
>          }
>          else {
>              NSLog(@"Sending Tweet!");
>          }
>      }];

Answer (score 0):

**Tweet Using SDK**
1. Crearte App on twitter.developer
2. add twitter frameworks like TwitterCore.framework, TwitterKit.framework, Fabric.framework, TwitterKitResources.bundle
3. write below code in tweet button

```
  [[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"YourConsumerKey" consumerSecret:@"YourConsumerSecret"];
  [Fabric with:@[[Twitter sharedInstance]]];

  [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) 
  {
    if (session) 
    {
        NSLog(@"logged in user with id %@", session.userID);

        TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];
        [composer setText:@"Enter Your Tweet Message"];
        //[composer setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fabric"]];
        [composer showFromViewController:self completion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {
            if (result == TWTRComposerResultCancelled) 
            {
                NSLog(@"Tweet composition cancelled");
            }
            else 
            {
                NSLog(@"Sending Tweet!");
                UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Sent Tweet!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [warningAlert show];
            }
        }];

    } 
    else 
    {
        // log error
    }
 }];
```